# How does react components use data without passing as props

Tags: reactjs, jsx

For example:

> ```
> <h1> Hello </h1>
> ```

Here Hello is used by components without passing it in props

Comment: You don't have to pass it as a props because it is just a text. If it was a variable sent from its parent, it must be passed as a props, but the code would be `<h1> {this.props.varName} </h1>

Comment: @HuLuViCa But how does <h1> component access the text for display. Ill give you another example.

`                    <Typography variant="h6" >
                        Dashboard  
                    </Typography>
`
How is "Dashboard" text accessible to <Typography>

Comment: @hulu-vica can you please clarify.  (Typography is material ui component)

Answer (score 1):

Anything between those tags still gets passed to the component as a prop named `children`. If you have something like this

```js
<Greet>Jon</Greet>
```

then you can access that in the Greet component like this

```js
function Greet({ children }) {
   return <div>Hello {children}</div>
}
```